# Core Data: when to 'free' unused NSManagedObjects with [ refreshObject:obj mergeChanges:NO]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm working on my first Core Data project, basing the NSManagedObjectModel development stage on Xcode's (Universal) Master-Detail template. The store based upon the ObjectModel is already populated with instances of various objects.

The Nav Controller table view is populated with the 12 top level "Structures", each of which has a "DefaultSpace" associated with it. When a table row is selected, the Detail view is populated with various UIView subclasses based on the properties of the DefaultSpace.
From here on, I employ a range of temporary NSObject subclasses to respond to user interaction  (some of which will be replaced by NSManagedObjects when I have developed this stage enough to more fully understand the persistence needs).

Hence when I have done some testing in Detail view for a given DefaultSpace and return to the Master table to select another Structure's DefaultSpace, I expect ARC to release the NSObjects no longer needed. In my naivety, I also expected Core Data to do the same with NSManagedObjects, but Instruments shows me that is not the case.

As far as I understand 
  `[managedObjectContext refreshObject:obj mergeChanges:NO];` is the method used to turn the now redundant child objects into faults. This, however, *seems* to mean traversing the chain of relationships and calling `[managedObjectContext refreshObject:obj mergeChanges:NO];` on each subordinate NSManagedObject.
My question is (in what circumstances) should I do this or should I mostly allow Core Data to decide when to 'clean up' unused objects?

Comment: I created my own CD garbage collector when I ran into this same issue. garbage = objects not viewable anywhere in your UI.

Comment: @nielsbot sounds like you are fighting the frameworks. Core Data cleans itself up very nicely without the need of any form of garbage collector.

Comment: I am talking about keeping a local object graph in sync with an object graph on the server. When objects are deleted from the server, I needed to  remove them from device after a sync. But looks like my comment doesn't apply to this tread, I should read more carefully. I'll show myself out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly you can just let Core Data to do its thing here. Re-faulting objects is a useful thing to do when you're loading lots of them, especially if the individual instances have a lot of data. In that case, get rid of them as soon as you're done with them. In most cases, however, this is completely unnecessary. Just treat them like any other object, unless you have reason to expect memory pressure. For the most part I only re-fault objects when doing custom migrations of potentially large data stores-- where I *know* I'm going to be loading a lot of data and need to be more careful about managing it.

Comment: I would also add that thinking about this before the app is done is a form of pre-optimization.  Don't assume Core Data is going to be a memory problem, wait until you can prove it via Instruments.

Comment: In my case, the DefaultSpace would fetch with it possibly 100 objects of 100byte-order size; I presume you're talking of the order of 100's of objects of kB-order size? Thanks also, Marcus, for pre-optimization comment.

Comment: @cate, right, at least that big. For the use you describe, I wouldn't bother with re-faulting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (feel free to correct any errors):

CoreData manage memory in the context and coordinator levels (the coordinator could be thought of as a "master cache").

In the coordinator level there is very little you can do. CoreData is doing the bookkeeping for objects being used there (if you fetch an object through that coordinator its "snapshot" is kept in that coordinator an following fetches for that object will be faster).
Try and dispose of contexts that you no longer use or reset them.

In the context level, CoreData is only reclaiming memory when it must (events such as "memory warning", "process pending changes").
For example, when you save a context, all objects that you haven't kept a strong reference to will be released by the context.
Objects fetched are strongly held by other objects having relationships to them, and these bonds must be broken "manually" (its enough for you to keep a single object for a large piece of your object graph to get retained in memory).

Something that might help: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954690/how-to-properly-trim-object-graph-brought-in-by-nsfetchedresultscontroller/20967889#20967889)

Comment: useful as linked discussion cautions against 'forcing faults' on objects fetched by NSFetchedResultsController; in my case only the "Structures" are fetched to populate the table, but I can imagine scenario where DefaultSpace could be too, thus causing problem by over-anxious use of `[managedObjectContext refreshObject:obj mergeChanges:NO]`